# std::set elements' reference and pointer invariance after insertion

Tags: c++, c++17, std

I came across a paragraph on [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/insert) that I don't think I understand:

> No iterators or references are invalidated. [If the insertion is successful, pointers and references to the element obtained while it is held in the node handle are invalidated, and pointers and references obtained to that element before it was extracted become valid. (since C++17)]

I expect that `No iterators or references` *to already existing objects within the set* `are invalidated` means that the following is correct:

```
    std::set<person> set{person{"Kate", "Oceanic"}};
    const auto &kate = *set.cbegin();

    std::cout << kate.flight << std::endl;

    // this does not invalidate reference to Kate
    set.insert(person{"John", "Oceanic815"});
    std::cout << kate.flight << std::endl;
```

But I don't get what the part for C++17 means: `...pointers and references to the element obtained while it is held in the node handle are invalidated, ...` Does *node handle* refer to an *iterator*?
`... and pointers and references obtained to that element before it was extracted become valid` What does exactly *become* mean here?

The full [example](https://godbolt.org/z/j5bx9YzKz):

```
#include <set>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

struct person
{
    std::string name;
    std::string flight;

    bool operator<(const person& other) const
    {
        return name < other.name;
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::set<person> set{person{"Kate", "Oceanic"}};
    const auto &kate = *set.cbegin();

    std::cout << kate.flight << std::endl;

    // this does not invalidate Kate
    set.insert(person{"John", "Oceanic815"});
    std::cout << kate.flight << std::endl;

    // is new Kate created within the same address?
    set.insert(person{"Kate", "Oceanic815"});
    std::cout << kate.flight << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Check out the `extract` and `merge` functions.  That'll explain what a node handle is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does *node handle* refer to an *iterator*?

No.

A "node handle", introduced in C++17, refers to the data structure internal to a `std::set` used to hold a single element.  It's what the `std::set` will allocate from the free store to hold the element and any related data structures, such as pointers and flags.

A handle to this structure allows elements to be removed from a set (via [`std::set::extract`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/extract)) without triggering a memory deallocation, and added to a set without triggering a memory allocation.

> > and pointers and references obtained to that element before it was extracted become valid
>
> What does exactly *become* mean here?

It means that pointers and references to an element in a *node handle* are invalid when they are *extracted*, but they are valid once again when that same *node handle* is inserted back into a set.

Comment: does it have to be *that same* node, or any other node which after insertion happens to be in "the old place"?

Comment: cppreference is describing the properties of a _particular node_.  `std::set` does not recognize the existence or concept of an "old place" that a node might occupy.

Answer (score 1):

A *node-handle* is NOT an iterator. A *node-handle* is a thing that you get when you call `extract` to remove a range of nodes from a `set` (say).  See [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/node_handle) for more.